# Comparing validity measure of K Means PAM DBSCAN and Fuzzy K Means

Tags: r, clustering, validation

I analyze the cancellation of shopping baskets of different types of customers using cluster methods. My data set contains 821,000 entries and 9 variables. I have used the cluster procedures K Means, PAM, DBSCAN, and Fuzzy K Means. I have validated the procedures using validity metrics and would like to compare the performance of the 4 procedures. Especially DBSCAN and Fuzzy K means cause me difficulties.

For K means and PAM, I have had the validity indices output with the cluster.stats package and have also calculated calinski harabasz.

Furthermore, I have chosen the cdbw index and calinksi harabasz for DBSCAN. With DBSCAN I have read that many of the indexes that cluster.stats outputs cannot be used for DBSCAN because they do not take into account noise data. How can I determine ss within cluster ss and between cluster ss for DBSCAN?

Concerning Fuzzy K Means I have calculated fuzzy validity indices like PE, PC, MPC, SlL.F. For Fuzzy K Means I also got the validity figures of the cluster.stats package. Is it possible to have the validity figures of the cluster.stats output for Fuzzy K means and then compare them with the values of k means and PAM? Or do the fuzzy values have to be converted into crisp values?

I am using R.

```
WKA_ohneJB <- read.csv("WKA_ohneJB_PCA.csv", header=TRUE, sep = ";", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# Select subset: WKA = 1

Baur_WKA <- subset(WKA_ohneJB, WKA == 1)
```

#

#### z-standardization of numerical variables

## scale dataset

```
Baur <- Baur_WKA[c(2,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11)]

Baur_scale <- scale(Baur)


set.seed (123)

sample <- Baur_scale[sample(nrow(Baur_scale), 10000), ]
```

## DBSCAN

## Cluster 4 + sample 10.000

```
dbscan::kNNdistplot(sample, k= 10) 
abline(h=2.5, col = "red", lty=2)

density_clust <- fpc::dbscan(sample, eps = 2.5, MinPts = 10)
density_clust

0    1   2
border 162   89   3
seed     0 9624 122
total  162 9713 125
```

## plot

```
fviz_cluster(density_clust , data = sample, stand = FALSE, ellipse = FALSE, show.clust.cent = FALSE, geom
```

Comment: it should be possible to implement the other measures, as long as you have the code for one. Let's say for within SS and between SS, you can use anova in R, and set the clus identity as a factor.

Comment: @StupidWolf I added part of my code. Concerning the assumption of the ANOVA most of my variables are right-skewed with significant outliers.  What is the clus identity?

Comment: @ StupidWolf I added part of my code. Concerning the assumptions of One way ANOVA most of my variables are right skewed with significant outliers. Could you tell my what the clus identity is please?